# How to detect height jsPDF-AutoTable

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am using jspdf autotable plugin (jspdf.plugin.autotable.js and jspdf.min.js)
to make table grid view in PDF document.
this is my code bellow:

```
var listpaket2 = '<?php echo json_encode($new_array_list_paket_min_15_persen); ?>'
var columns = ["Nama Balai","Kode Satker","Kode PPK","Nama "];
var rows = jQuery.parseJSON(listpaket2); //listpaket2 contains dynamic big data, it is about 5000 rows of record

doc.autoTable(columns, rows, {
  styles: {fillColor: [100, 255, 255]},
  columnStyles: {
    id: {fillColor: 255}
  },
  addPageContent: function(data) {
  }
});

alert(doc.height)
```

when I am doing `alert(doc.height)`I got "undefined". that is not as my expectation.
How to detect table height when table contains big data?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the new table height each time a cell was drawn, using the provided [hooks](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable#options) like this:

```
var height = 0;
doc.autoTable(columns, rows, {
    styles: {fillColor: [100, 255, 255]},
    columnStyles: {
        id: {fillColor: 255}
    },
    addPageContent: function(data) {},
    createdCell: function (cell, data) {
        height = data.table.height
    }
});
alert(height)
```

Now the above implementation works up to v2.3.5, v3 was pre-release only 4 days ago (at time of writing), then this hook will be removed. At this time it looks like you can use the new hook : `didParseCell` like this:

```
var height = 0;
doc.autoTable(columns, rows, {
    styles: {fillColor: [100, 255, 255]},
    columnStyles: {
        id: {fillColor: 255}
    },
    didParseCell: function (HookData) {
        height = HookData.table.height
    }
});
alert(height)
```

Note that addPageContent will also be removed in v3. Other things might still change, check your implementation if you decide to upgrade.

Comment: so this code used for jspdfautotable version 2.xx
 createdCell: function (cell, data) {
       height = data.table.height
 }

Comment: I am using jspdf version 2.xx and following your instruction above. there are no change. I get 0 in alert message

Answer (score 1):

Use the `didDrawPage` hook passing a function like below to get the ending height of the table.

```js
autoTable(doc, {
  ...,
  didDrawPage: (d) => console.log(d.cursor.y),
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to set the height within the `didParseCell` hook did not work. You can capture the data from that hook and get the height after the table finishes.

```
let height = 0;
let tableMeta = null;

doc.autoTable(columns, rows, {
    styles: {fillColor: [100, 255, 255]},
    columnStyles: {
        id: {fillColor: 255}
    },
    didParseCell: (data) => {
        if (!tableMeta) {
            tableMeta = data.table;
            height = data.table.height; // <- doesn't work, sets height to 0
        }
    }
});

// Calculate the table height
height = tableMeta.finalY - tableMeta.pageStartY;

// Or the final Y position after drawing the table if that's what you need
height = tableMeta.height;

alert(height);
```